# Change Blur events with javascript event delegation

Tags: javascript, event-delegation

I have a form that is dynamically added to the DOM and therefore I have to use event delegation.

I can not get this to fire and it looks to me like this event can only be attached to an input element

```js
['change', 'blur'].forEach(event => {
  document.addEventListener(event, e => {
    if (e.target.closest('.dynamic-modal form input')) {
      const $input = e.target.closest('.dynamic-modal form input')
      console.log($input)
      // never logs on change and blur
    }

  })
})
```

How can I go about solving this?

Comment: The [`blur` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/blur_event) does not bubble. For the [`change` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event) it should work.

Comment: @Bergi In the capturing phase when the event reaches the target it is captured into the $input variable. Is it wrong that the blur and change events here are being attached to the document?

Comment: "*I have to use event delegation*" - no, you can also attach the event handlers dynamically when adding the form to the DOM. Can you show that code, please?

Comment: Got it to work, thank you! I did not know that you could attach an event listener in this manner